# Python list of strings that only include a specific word

Tags: python, sorting, amazon-s3

I want to loop through list A and find every place my sublist is in list A. In real situations there would be several items listed with same partitions leading to different files. I do see several post here that does this but haven't gotten it to work.

My issue sstart with this (removed extra info not needed in code chunk for size)
I do an s3 bucket list

```
response = {
  "ResponseMetadata": {

    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
   ,
  "IsTruncated": False,
  "Contents": [
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature/index.html",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature/manifest.json",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature2/index.html",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature2/manifest.json",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature3/index.html",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "Key": "staging/new-feature3/manifest.json",
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    }
  ],
  "Name": "bucket",
  "Prefix": "staging/new-feature",
  "MaxKeys": 1000,
  "KeyCount": 6
}
```

Then i reduce the response down to only the keys:

```
new_objects = response["Contents"]
new_object = [sub["Key"] for sub in new_objects]
```

my result:

```
['staging/new-feature/index.html', 'staging/new-feature/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature2/index.html', 'staging/new-feature2/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature3/index.html', 'staging/new-feature3/manifest.json']
```

I only want keys that include my sub-string:
In this situation:

```
sub_string= new-feature2
```

I would like to get this only

```
['staging/new-feature2/index.html','staging/new-feature2/manifest.json']
```

so i can then

```
final_list = []
    for items in delete_key_objects:
        delete_files.append({"Key": items})

print("final_list")
[{"Key": "staging/new-feature/manifest.json"}, {"Key": "staging/new-feature2/manifest.index"}]
```

which can then be deleted from s3 using delete objects

I've tried:

```
new_object = [sub["Key"] for sub in new_objects]
delete_key_objects = [
                   i for i in new_object for j in sub_string if str(j) in i]
```

as well as

```
delete_files=[]
for text in new_object:
    if sub_string in text:
       delete_files.append({"Key": sub_string})
```

and a few other things each time it returns items that should not be placed in the delete files list

Comment: Do you mean just add an `if` to your list-comp, eg: `new_object = [sub["Key"] for sub in new_objects if 'new-feature2' in sub["Key"]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get all items with the pattern "new-feature2" from your final list, use a list comprehension and a conditional as shown below.

```
new_object = ['staging/new-feature/index.html', 'staging/new-feature/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature2/index.html', 'staging/new-feature2/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature3/index.html', 'staging/new-feature3/manifest.json']
pattern = 'new-feature2'
delete_objects = [x for x in new_object if pattern in x]
```

get all objects in new_object if pattern in object.

Comment: I tried using your way @harry . I changed pattern to a variable passed through the function.   delete_objects = [x for x in new_object if staging_env in x] but my result was                                                                                                                    ['staging/new-feature/index.html', 'staging/new-feature/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature2/index.html', 'staging/new-feature2/manifest.json', 'staging/new-feature3/index.html', 'staging/new-feature3/manifest.json']